# Why is $Set$ not equivalent to $Set^{op}$?

Tags: category-theory

I understand this question already has an answer on here, but I do not understand how the answer justifies that $Set$ not equivalent to $Set^{op}$.

The explanation is that if they were equivalent and if the terminal object in $Set$ has an equivalence invariant property, then the initial object has the dual property.

The terminal objects are obviously singleton sets, and the initial object is the empty set. I can see that every map into the empty set is an isomorphism, and that there exists maps $\{a\}\to X$ which are not invertible, but how does this relate to the non-equivalence of $Set$ and $Set^{op}$?

If someone could elaborate further I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second paragraph is the explanation. Try dualising the two properties in question.

Comment: It is even easier to observe that $\mathbf{Set}$ has an arrow from a terminal object to a non-terminal one, but $\mathbf{Set}^{\rm op}$ does not (such an arrow would a function from a nonempty set to the empty set).

Comment: But why is the explanation in the second paragraph true? It just seems odd to show a nonequivalence f a category and its opposite by just talking about one.

Comment: The part as to why we can make this conclusion without even considering $Set^{op}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're referring to the fact that in $\mathbf{Set}$ we have maps from singletons to other sets, but in $\mathbf{Set}^{\rm op}$ the singletons cannot map into the empty set?

Comment: @BrandonThomasVanOver: No, in the comment above I'm only mentioning terminal objects. The terminal objects in $\mathbf{Set}$ are the singletons, but the terminal object in $\mathbf{Set}^{\rm op}$ is the empty set. So I'm not speaking about singletons in the context of $\mathbf{Set}^{\rm op}$ at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the following property of a category $\mathcal C$:

> If $f: A\to B$ is a morphism and $B$ is an initial object, then $f$ is an isomorphism.

Since this property is stated only in terms of existence properties of certain morphisms (and does not depend on uniqueness of *objects* even if we unfold the definition of an initial object), if we have two equivalent categories they will either both have this property or both *not* have this property.

The explanation you reproduce consists of the observation that $\mathbf{Set}$ has this property (because the only morphism into an initial object is the empty function $\varnothing\to\varnothing$, which is an isomorphism), whereas $\mathbf{Set}^{\rm op}$ does not (there are functions with singleton domains that are not bijections, and such a function is in $\mathbf{Set}^{\rm op}$ a non-iso morphism into an initial object).

Comment: So from my understand the singleton sets become initial in the opposite category, so why isn't it enough to say that not every map into a singleton is an isomorphism then?

Comment: @BrandonThomasVanOver: You're confusing the directions of morphisms and map. Remember that in $\mathbb{Set}^{\rm op}$ a _morphism_ from $A$ to $B$ is a _map_ from $B$ to $A$. So "morphism _into_ an initial object" in $\mathbf{Set}^{\rm op}$ is the same as "map _from_ a singleton".

Comment: @HenningMakholm, the homs in $Set^{op}$ are not maps (functions). You mention in your comment to the OP above that "such an arrow would [be] a function...".

Answer (score 3):

**Statement 1** : Let $C\simeq D$ be two categories which are equivalent thanks to a functor $F : C \to D$. If $X$ is an initial object in $C$ then $F(X)$ is an initial object in $D$.

**Statement 2** : If $X$ is an initial object in $C$ (for some category $C$), it is a terminal object in $C^{op}.$

**Statement 3** : If $F : C \to D$ is an equivalence between categories with products, one has $F(X \times Y) \simeq F(X) \times F(Y)$ for all $X,Y$.

Now suppose to have a functor $F : Set \to Set^{op}$ which gives an equivalence between them. Then, because $\emptyset$ is initial in $Set^{op}$, we get that $F(\emptyset)$ is initial in $Set^{op}$. (Statement 1). After that, we get that $F(\emptyset)$ is terminal in $Set$. (Statement 2). Hence, there is $a$ such that. $F(\emptyset) = \{a\} .$ Now apply statement 3 $$\{a\} = F(\emptyset) = F(\emptyset \times \emptyset) \simeq F(\emptyset) \times F(\emptyset) = \{a\} \bigsqcup \{a\}.$$ So you have established a bijection between $\{a\}$ and $\{a\} \bigsqcup \{a\},$ which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: The function $f: \{a\}\to\{a\}\times\{a\}$ given by $f(a) = \langle a,a\rangle$ is a bijection. (However, the categorical product in $\mathbf{Set}^{\rm op}$ is of course disjoint union, so what you actually need is a bijection between $\{a\}$ and $\{1\}\times\{a\}\cup\{2\}\times\{a\}$ which is still impossible).

Comment: Of course, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite to *Set* is the category of *Complete Atomic Boolean Algebras*, see

> https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Set#OppositeCategory